# Perl Encoding for Japanese characters

Tags: perl, encoding

Please help me for my Perl encode problem.

1. I create html form with some input fields.
2. I take parameters from input "name".
3. Form action is ".pl" file.

and then I filled the data input fields. and take parameter and I can see the data that I filled. But not OK for Japanese characters.

How to use `Encode` for that case? e.g Japanese character become `ã­ã“`.

Comment: Thanks for your edit to clear.
:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you are seting the character encoding of your web page correctly. Usually UTF-8. So if you're using the CGI module you do something like:

```
my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header( -charset=> 'utf-8' );
```

This is assuming your form is also generated by by the perl CGI. If its flat HTML, there are some META tags you can use to acomplish the same thing. I think its

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: I can see my filled Japanese character on browsers now.
Thanks a lot for your help.
:)